# Returning Complex Type from Stored Procedure in EntityFramework "CodeFirst"

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, dbcontext, complextype

I am using "CodeFirst Existing Database" and have introduced a stored procedure from mycontext class which seems fine but the entity i am mapping to has a complex type.

**MyContext**

```
public virtual List<Student> Get_AllStudents(int year, string classes, string indicators) {
        StringBuilder spCommand = new StringBuilder();// = "CALL Get_AllStudents(";
        //params object[] parameters;
        MySqlParameter[] mySqlParams = new MySqlParameter[]{new MySqlParameter("yearId", year),
                                                        new MySqlParameter("classIds", classes),
                                                        new MySqlParameter("indicatorList", indicators)};
        spCommand.Append("CALL Get_AllStudents(@yearId,@classIds,@indicatorList);");

        return this.Database.SqlQuery<Student>(spCommand.ToString(), mySqlParams).ToList<Student>();

    }
```

and my **query** is

```
select s.firstname, s.surname,s.IndicatorID from students s
    where ClassId in (classIds)
    and yearId = yearId
    and indicatorId in (indicatorList);
```

My **Student** Entity has a complex type "Name"

```
 public class Student
{
    public int studentID { get; set; }
    public string studentCode { get; set; }        
    public Name name { get; set; }


   public Nullable<System.DateTime> birthdate { get; set; }
}

public class Name {
    [Column("surname")]
    public string surname { get; set; }
    [Column("middlename")]
    public string middlename { get; set; }
    [Column("firstname")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    [Column("preferredname")]
    public string preferredname { get; set; }
}
```

How do i tell entity framework to map s.firstname and s.surname to map to Student.Name.firstname and Student.Name.surname properties

I havent used import function (as it is giving me some stupid error i dont want to deal with "Your project references the latest version of EntityFramework however EF data provider compatible with this version cannot be found...") can i change some sp settings in mycontext class to expect complex type?

**Error**
Cannot create a value for property 'name' of type 'DbContexts.Name'.
Only properties of primitive or enumeration types are supported.